# git - Como copiar un archivo y mantener la historia de dicho archivo al hacer blame?

Tags: git

Si se copia un archivo directamente en git, git no es capaz de vez de donde viene el archivo:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --name-status master
* 70f03aa (master) COpying file straight
| A     new_file.txt
* efc04f3 (first) First commit for file
  A     hello_world.txt
$ git diff master:new_file.txt master:hello_world.txt 
$ git blame -s master -- hello_world.txt
^efc04f3 1) I am here
^efc04f3 2) 
^efc04f3 3) Yes I am
$ git blame -s master -- new_file.txt
70f03aab 1) I am here
70f03aab 2) 
70f03aab 3) Yes I am
$ git blame -s --follow master -- new_file.txt
70f03aab 1) I am here
70f03aab 2) 
70f03aab 3) Yes I am
```

Hay alguna forma de lograr que git *conecte* el archivo nuevo con el original?

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede hacer, pero requiere de algo de trabajo con una rama adicional para lograr *engañar* a git.

```
git checkout -b rama-renombrar
git mv a.txt b.txt
git commit -m "Renombrando un archivo"
# Si se hace un git blame de b.txt, la historia _seguiría_ a a.txt, cierto?
git checkout main
git merge --no-ff --no-commit rama-renombrar
git checkout HEAD -- a.txt # recuperar el archivo original
git commit -m "No estamos renombrando el archivo"
```

Utilizando este truco con los archivos usados en la pregunta original:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph master2 --name-status
*   30b76ab (HEAD, master2) Not really renaming
|\  
| * 652921f Renaming file
|/  
|   R100        hello_world.txt new_file.txt
* efc04f3 (first) First commit for file
  A     hello_world.txt
$ git log --oneline --graph --name-status master2 -- new_file.txt
* 652921f Renaming file
  A     new_file.txt
$ git log --oneline --graph --follow --name-status master2 -- new_file.txt
... 
| * 652921f Renaming file
|/  
|   R100        hello_world.txt new_file.txt
* efc04f3 (first) First commit for file
  A     hello_world.txt
$ git blame -s master2 -- new_file.txt
^efc04f3 hello_world.txt 1) I am here
^efc04f3 hello_world.txt 2) 
^efc04f3 hello_world.txt 3) Yes I am
$ git blame -s master2 -- hello_world.txt
^efc04f3 1) I am here
^efc04f3 2) 
^efc04f3 3) Yes I am
```

La explicación es que si se quiere ver la historia del archivo original, git no tiene problemas para seguirla. Si se quiere ver la historia del archivo copiado, git tiene que seguir la historia de la rama con el renombre ya que ese archivo viene de *esa rama* y entonces git si puede encontrar el renombre en la historia y conecta con el archivo original.